# I want to open a second form AFTER opening the main form, but the second form opens first

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to open a secondary form immediately after the main form displays, but instead, the secondary form displays first and then the main form displays after the secondary one closes (The second form is acting like a splash screen). Here is an example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething1(sender, e);
        doSomething2(sender, e);
        // The new form I want to open after the main form.
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        doSomething3(sender, e);
    }
    private void doSomething1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
    private void doSomething2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
    private void doSomething3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
```

Comment: You should put that in the show handler of the main form instead of the load handler.

Comment: Glad to hear it! The order of events in Winforms can be a bit tricky; you might want to take a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx for more info on the sequence in which each type of event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Form1.Shown` event instead of the `Load` event:

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    doSomething1(sender, e);
    doSomething2(sender, e);
    // The new form I want to open after the main form.
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    doSomething3(sender, e);
}
```

Alternatively, depending on whether `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` are doing background processing that the user doesn't need to see: you could retain those two in the load handler, and merely move the last two statements into the `Shown` handler.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor initialized the `Shown` event handler first:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
    }
```

Then put the code there:

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      doSomething1(sender, e);
      doSomething2(sender, e);
      // The new form I want to open after the main form.
      Form2 f2 = new Form2();
      doSomething3(sender, e);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
```